# The output is not displayed correctly formatted when i get output with ssh connection remotely with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, pexpect

I connect to remote server with ssh with my python codes.
I connect and get results. But results are coming with \r\n
My codes are below :

```
#To connect remote server and run networkmon.py and get results
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = "10.89.71.39"
    username = "manoadmin"
    password = "********" #generic pass added
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('cat manobackup_scripts/networkmon.py')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh login hata.")
```

The output i get is like;

> import os\r\nimport socket\r\n\r\nimport time\r\n\r\nstart_time = time.time()\r\n\r\n

But i want the out put to be printed out as below

> import os
> import socket
>
> import time
>
> start_time = time.time()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default data in `s.before` is of `bytes`, not `str`. You can decode when printing:

```
print(s.before.decode() )
```

You can ask it to automatically convert the data to `str` by specifying an `encoding`:

```
s = pxssh.pxssh(encoding='utf8')
...
print(s.before)
```